# awk process own field value

Tags: csv, awk

I have a CSV file formatted like this:

```
Postcode,Count,Total
L1 3RT,20,345.65
```

I am summing the counts and totals by Postcode using awk, however I'd like to do this for the first portion of a postcode (ie L1, thus combining the values for L1 3RT and L2 4XW). Sample data and existing awk command shown below.

```
CM1 4QR,979,32950.8
CM1 4QS,2,145.14
CM13 1DL,115,3771
```

AWK line

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "," } ; {sums[$1] += $2; totals[$1] += $3} END { for (i in sums) printf("%s,%s,%i\n", i, sums[i],totals[i])}' coach.csv
```

I would like the output to be

```
CM1,981,33095.94
CM13,115,3771
```

Comment: You can pipe `$1` through awk again using space as the delimiter.  Then you will get the first portion of your postcode, and then use that as the index to the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works:

```
awk -F'[ ,]' '
{
  sums[$1] += $3; 
  totals[$1] += $4;
} 
END { 
  for (i in sums) 
    printf("%s,%i,%i\n", i, sums[i],totals[i]);
}' coach.csv
```

It uses two delimiters, the comma and space.  It works for your sample input, but won't for more complex input that has spaces elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple delimiters in awk. Please try this

```
awk -F'[, ]' '{sums[$1] += $3; totals[$1] += $4} END {for (i in sums) printf("%s,%.2f,%.2f\n", i, sums[i], totals[i])}' coach.csv
```